# componentWillReceiveProps() is not executing in child component?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have two react component `parent` and `child` both of them are connected to the `redux` `store` to same object and the object get data from server `asynchronously`

**Problem:** on receiving new props parent's  `componentWillReceiveProps`
get executed but child's  `componentWillReceiveProps` is not executing
any idea??

**child component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class Child extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleUserClick = this.handleUserClick.bind(this)

  }

  handleUserClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let userInfo = {
      email: 'someEmail@gmail.com',
      password: 'password',
    };
    this.props.someAction(userInfo); // changes the store but on store change componentWillReceiveProps not executing
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log(nextProps)
  }


 render(){
    return (
       <div><form onSubmit={this.handleUserClick}></form></div>
  )
  }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {  someAction: someAction}, dispatch)
}

function mapStateToProps (state){
  return {
    dummyState: state.dummyState
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Child);
```

when i'm clicking `handleUserClick` is get executed but on receiving data from server  `child` `componentWillReceiveProps` is not executing but `parent` `componentWillReceiveProps` is executing

my parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {parentState: 0}
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.someAction(); // same action called in child component
  }

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   // it gets executed and call child render function
    if(nextProps.something === true){
       this.setState({parentState: 1 })
  }
    if(nextProps.something === false){
      this.setState({parentState: -1})
    }

  }


  render() {

    if(this.state.parentState == -1){
      return(
      <Child/>
       )
    }
    else{
      return(null)
    }
  }
}



function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {  someAction: someAction}, dispatch)  //same action in child component called
}



function mapStateToProps (state){
  return {
    dummyState: state.dummyState  // //same state in child component called
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Parent);
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is the first time that the child is rendered (you set `renderChild` to `true`) then `componentWillReceiveProps` is not called (this is for updates). You should look into `componentWillMount` instead.

If you se the `renderChild` state to `true` when it was already `true`, nothing will happen.

Comment: Try using `componentWillMount` in the child.

Comment: i need to use setState and using `componentWillMount` wil not call render

Comment: It's called before the first render, so no, it won't trigger a render, but render will be called afterwards anyway. You can use setState there.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a couple of reasons

1. Your reducer is not updating and the state is the remains same.
2. Your reducer is updating the state but its the exact same values thus the component parent component and child component is not being re-rendered.
3. If you are not passing changed props into the child component and you are relying redux to render then it could be you misnamed the name of the state attribute that is updating.

If you provided more src code such as your action creator, reducer, and a little bit more source it'll be easier to debug.

Comment: Looking at the parent container it looks like the child component is being unmounted potential at some point. It could be the case that the child component is being unmounted and then mounted again because of the logic and thats why you aren't seeing the componentWillReceiveProps being fired off. 

Try adding componentWillUnmount(){console.log("Child is unmounted");} to your child component and see how often its called. This may be your issue